# Widgets in tableview or scrollview Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona and I want to make a collapsed tableview which scrolls,
that has widgets in it, like checkboxes, buttons and pickerwheels.
Is that possible?

Thanks for det help!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newTableView.html, have a look at this api. Here there s an function called insert rows in that function you can add widgets to each you create in an table view.